# Minimize Function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, optimization

I wish to minimize (using fmincon or similar) the following function:

```
function Difference= myfun3(wk,omega,lambda,Passetcovar,tau,PMat,i,Pi,Q)
  wcalc=inv(lambda* Passetcovar)*inv(inv(tau * Passetcovar)+ PMat(i,:)'*inv(omega)*PMat(i,:))*(inv(tau * Passetcovar)*Pi+ PMat(i,:)'*inv(omega)*Q(i,:));
  Difference=sum((wk-wcalc).^2);
end
```

`wk` and `wcalc` are <8 x 1 double> column vectors where wk is known and wcalc is given by the above equation.

How do I minimize `Difference` by varying `Omega` for `Omega >0` with

- lambda- Scalar
- Passetcovar-   <8 x 8 double>
- tau - Scalar
- PMat- <3 x 8 double>
- Omega- Scalar
- Q- <3 x 1 double>
- Pi- <8 x 1 double>

Comment: You generally need to some things about the function in order to be sure that a local minimum is, in fact, the global minimum (for example, the function is convex).  Is this the case?

Comment: What do you mean by 'minimize f', it is not a scalar right?

Comment: Sorry, Yes, it is a scalar @Dennis Jaheruddin.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to call a variable diff, as that will conflict with a tremendously useful tool in matlab - diff. The uppercase D will prevent the direct name conflict, but still, it is poor style since this may make things confusing at some point later on for you.

Comment: Also, you should tell us the shapes of these arrays, as I will bet (with confidence) that the minimization can be done using linear algebra, not a minimizer. However, I won't make the effort to write it out unless I know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @woodchips. Thank you for your comments. I have edited the question accordingly and I hope this answers your questions and concerns?

Comment: Next, as with the function diff, avoid using the variable Pi. I had to check to see if you meant pi, the number 3.1415926535... or some variable you have defined. I found it in the calling arguments though. What you have not told us is Pi scalar? Vector? An array?

Comment: Apologies, yes Pi is a column vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, is `sigma` a row vector? If not, then `f` is a vector too. Are you trying multi-objective optimization? Then `fminsearch` will not help.

Second, read the documentation of [`fminsearch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html) before using it. `f` is supposed to be a function which maps your input vector to a scalar. Also, it needs a start point `x0`.

Therefore, write a function `f` which takes in `omega` and returns the a scalar objective function value. Also, figure out a feasible `x0` (i.e a starting value for `omega`).

Third, `fminsearch` does not allow constraints. You could hack it by making `f` return `Inf` or something when `omega <= 0`. I would recommend [`fmincon`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html).

Your function should look like this. Make sure all the other variables like `PMap,tau`,etc. are globally accessible. Otherwise, you'll need an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) to pass to `fminsearch`.

```
obj = f(omega)
wcalc=inv(lambda* sigma)*inv(inv(tau * sigma)+ PMap(i,:)'*inv(Omega)*PMap(i,:))*(inv(tau * sigma)*pi+ PMap(i,:)'*inv(Omega)*Q(i,:));
obj = sigma*(wk-wcalc).^2;
```

Then use `fmincon`. Assume you have a starting value for `omega`.

```
fmincon(f,omega,[],[],[],[],0,Inf);
```

The `[]` are added since we only want to bound your solutions from below using this form.

```
x = fmincon(fun,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub)
```

Does your `f` looks like this?

```
obj = f(omega,PMap,sigma,.....)
```

Where the `......` represents all the other variables. Then you can use [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html)  in the following manner.

```
g = @(omega)f(omega,PMap,sigma,.....);
```

Now you can use `g` in `fmincon` or `fminsearch`.

Comment: Thank you. I do not need to necessarily use fminsearch. I have tried to set up the problem as you describe for fmincom but get errors. Do I need to save some parts separately?

Comment: does fmincon handle f if f is a vector?

Comment: @Mary: No. If your objective function returns a vector, you're doing multi-objective optimization. `fmincon`, `fminsearch`, etc. does single-objective optimization.

Comment: I have followed your instructions and come up with:`sigma=cell2mat(Passetcovar);
function wcalc = f(x);
lambda=3.07;

wcalc= inv(lambda* sigma)*inv(inv(tau * sigma)+ PMap(i,:)'*inv(x)*PMap(i,:))*(inv(tau * sigma)*pi+ PMap(i,:)'*inv(x)*Q(i,:));
Diff=sum((wk-wcalc).^2).`   I then call it using `fmincon(f,x,[],[],[],[],0,Inf);` but I get the following error. @Jacob I am unable to work out why... any ideas? Many thanks

Comment: the error is _Function definitions are not permitted in this context._

Answer (score 3):

You generally need to some things about the function in order to be sure that a local minimum is, in fact, the global minimum (for example, the function is convex). Is this the case?

Assuming it is, or you just want to find a local minima, consider the following example:

```
clear all
close all
clc

f = @(x) (x+3).^2;

x = linspace(-5,5,100);
y = f(x);
plot(x,y);

ymin = fminsearch(f, 0);
printf('Local min found at: %f\n', ymin);
```

Which displays a simple graph and prints:

```
Local min found at: -3.000000
```

Note that you have to specify a starting point for the search.  In this case, I used 0.  When you only give `fminsearch` a single parameter, it expects the parameter to be a structure, which it doesn't look like you're using.

From `help fminsearch`:

```
X = fminsearch(PROBLEM) finds the minimum for PROBLEM. PROBLEM is a
    structure with the function FUN in PROBLEM.objective, the start point
    in PROBLEM.x0, the options structure in PROBLEM.options, and solver
    name 'fminsearch' in PROBLEM.solver. The PROBLEM structure must have
    all the fields.
```

You likely want this usage:

```
X = fminsearch(FUN,X0) starts at X0 and attempts to find a local minimizer 
    X of the function FUN.  FUN is a function handle.  FUN accepts input X and 
    returns a scalar function value F evaluated at X. X0 can be a scalar, vector 
    or matrix.
```

Answer (score 2):

As you have a fairly complicated function, and only want to vary 1 scalar, I would say: consider using brute force.

Here is an example of how to do it (Assuming all required variables are defined).

```
rangeMin = 0;
rangeMax = 10; %Put an assumed upper bound for Omega here
stepNumber = 10000;
Omega = linspace(rangeMin, rangeMax, stepNumber);
result = Inf(size(Omega))
for t = 1:length(Omega)
    wcalc(t)=inv(lambda* sigma)*inv(inv(tau * sigma)+ PMap(i,:)'*inv(Omega(t))*PMap(i,:))*(inv(tau * sigma)*pi+ PMap(i,:)'*inv(Omega(t))*Q(i,:));
end

wcalcMin = min(wcalc)
OmegaMin = find(wcalc == wcalcMin)
```

If you want to see what the function actually looks like you can now do

```
plot(wcalc)
```

If you see that there are no extreme spikes, and that the function gently approaches local minima (rather than jumps there) this is probably a decent approach.

If you are satisfied with the function behavior, you can increase the accuracy by setting `rangeMin` and `rangeMax` to only evaluate your area of interest. If you are not satisfied with the behavior, you can try whether increasing `stepNumber` helps.

Comment: Please comment if you downvote. I did use the taboo words *brute force* but note that this is a very generally applicable approach that is even able to deal with multi objective optimization. Furthermores it is comparatively robust against getting trapped in local minima.

Answer (score 1):

This objective is NOT that terribly complicated. But you have written it to look complicated.

First of all, omega is a scalar! Why bother to write inv(omega)? Dividing by omega is a better idea, as it will not involve overhead for the inverse function.

Next, tau is a known constant scalar, as is Passetcovar. Why compute the inverse of the matrix (tau*Passetcovar) every time the function is called? Not only that, but you compute that same inverse matrix THREE times in one line. Learn to precompute these things. It will save you much time and many headaches.

Anyway, you have an obsession with inv. It is called 6 times in one single line, and most of those calls are superfluous.

Lets re-write that single line of yours. First of all, precompute inv(Passetcovar), passing in the whole thing into your objective, so you need to do it ONLY one time.

Note the basic identity:

```
inv(k*A) = inv(A)/k
```

which is valid for any non-zero scalar k.

```
IP = inv(Passetcovar);
```

Again, do not repeat the computation of inv(Passetcovar) every time the objective function is called. Instead, compute it ONCE, before you start the optimization.

So the computation becomes a bit simpler to read:

```
wcalc = IP./lambda*inv(IP./tau + PMat(i,:)'*PMat(i,:)/omega)*(IP*Pi./tau + PMat(i,:)'*Q(i,:)/omega);
```

Edit:

Finally we learn that Pi is a vector. I suppose it must be an 8x1 vector, in order for the array multiplication to conform.

We can save a few more divides and multiplies by factoring out some constants, and inserting a parens in a convenient place. Note that by computing the matrix*vector multiply FIRST, and then multiplying by IP, we convert a 8x8 * 8x8 multiply into a 8x8 X 8x1 multiply. For small arrays like this, the difference is not huge, but worth remembering the idea.

```
wcalc = IP*(inv(IP + tau*PMat(i,:)'*PMat(i,:)/omega)*(IP*Pi + PMat(i,:)'*Q(i,:)/omega*tau))/(lambda*tau^2);
```

The goal is to minimize a sum of squares between wcalc and wk, subject to positive omega. This is now a scalar.

I would suggest plotting the function first, just to learn something about the shape of it, and to see what might be a good starting value for omega. Thus, by wrapping a function handle around myfun, ezplot will do the plot nicely, here for a range of [0,100] for omega. Pick your own upper bound for omega if that is unreasonable.

```
ezplot(@(omega) myfun3(wk,omega,lambda,Passetcovar,tau,PMat,i,Pi,Q),[0,100])
```

So the trivial solution is to use fminbnd, providing some reasonable but sufficiently large value for an upper bound. A nice thing about fminbnd is it does not need starting values. You will need to choose a reasonable upper bound for omega. The point is, use a tool designed to minimize a scalar function. General optimizers like fmincon are not needed, and require a starting value.

```
finalomega = fminbnd(@(omega) myfun3(wk,omega,lambda,Passetcovar,tau,PMat,i,Pi,Q),[0,100])
```

You can also employ [fminsearchbnd](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8277-fminsearchbnd-fminsearchcon), found on the file exchange. It can minimize a function subject to only lower bound constraints, but fminsearchbnd will need a starting value for omega.